# ng-show isn't working on cross js file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/pysqmDkRbAt3cQhgGJ3h?p=preview

In line 3404 I added mouse hover event

```
ng-mouseover='showDeleteButton=true' ng-mouseleave='showDeleteButton=false'
```

and expect my delete button to show up where in my index.html line 16, I do `ng-show="showDeleteButton"`

is this scope problem? or I can't do this on 'cross js' file?

Comment: Have you posted a wrong plunkr? Can't find the code nor line 3404 anywhere in any of the files

Comment: @callmekatootie updated. thx for telling me that!

Comment: The directives have isolate scope so this isn't entirely trivial the scope isn't always shared across all directives you'll need to probably modify the directive so it calls a function on your scope when the mouse event happens instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DO NOT make changes to library files, especially one where it allows you the flexibility to have your own template file.

In this case, you have made changes directly into the source file which is not the way to use that library.

Instead, you need to create your own template using the `text/ng-template` type of script.

You can find this in the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script).

Ensure that you provide the ID of the script template as (since you are using tab directive) as:

```
template/tabs/tab.html
template/tabs/tabset.html
```

Two templates since the directive trascludes one into another.

See the reference templates [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/template/tabs)

Once you define your own template, you should then be able to achieve addition and deletion of tabs

Comment: but the example of official don't use template to do that? is this the only way? I don't get the things in the documentation though.

Comment: Yes, create your own template and proceed. What part of the documentation do you not understand? I have also highlighted the steps you need to take to create your own template, doesn't that help?

Comment: I'm half way to go, I would have to restart everything if I go for templating.

Comment: is there no any hack for my problem?

Comment: Don't chose short term gains over long term ones. Create your own template - it helps with maintenance later. Its an extra effort but making changes directly into the library will get out of hand soon. Plus, the library encourages you to create your own - its flexible to allow it and yet you want to make changes directly into it - I don't see any reason for the same.

Comment: thanks for the advise. This is their official example, http://plnkr.co/edit/UPBFw1xUt9Wkst4d1uwI?p=preview, they didn't use template right? now I'm confused how to use angularui properly.

Comment: They used the default templates - because their demo does not have such an explicit requirement as yours. When your requirements vary, you are free to create your own template

Comment: do you have any tutorial for creating template with angularui? I have no idea how to start.

Comment: Erm... See my answer. Read the documentation. You will be just fine.

Comment: pls provide me an example, I really have no idea how to start. I have read everything.